Pull-up and pull-down resistors values
This is my first project:

Do you think that all the pull-up and pull-dwn resistors value are good?
Do the capacitor are oversized?
Any suggestions about the circuit in general?
Thank you :)
Updates:


They could be. It sort of depends what you expect them to do and how quickly. If something must happen due to pull resistor, how quickly you want and expect it to happen? One thing is missing, a bypass cap for the RTC.

How is +12 V applied? If switched in, your 500 mA fuse may not be happy with charging up a 1 mF capacitor behind it.

@Justme I've updated the circuit. Something like this?

@winny There is an external DC power supply (a MeanWell one).
Actually the circuit is designed to work with two different power supply: One pre-optocouplers, and uno post-optocouplers...  but it's going to be really easy I'll use just one for everything.

That didn't answer my question. Is there any switch on the DC side or is it hard connected and only switched on the AC side?

@winny it's switched on on the AC side.

Good, then should be no issues there.

I would not use discrete level shifters. The gates on the inputs can be easily blown, and the outputs seem only to pull down. Do those NFC readers have a bus that's pulled high, like I2C? Even then, just go for a level shifter IC. It can be from the old CD4000 series if you wish - not super fast, but you don't need super fast, I don't think.

How can be easily blown? Are you referring to the 2n7000 Q8 and Q9 (for example) ?
